# Print the name opposite to Max value in a struct

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, struct

#### The problem is in the print winner function

this code is for an election between a given number of candidates by user and then calcutes the votes for each candidate

I want to print max value of the candidate struct which has two cases

Case 1 : 1 max value

Case 2 : 2 max values

and is it possible to do it using less variable in the print winner function?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
     }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;




}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int max = 0;
    int i;
    int index;
    for (i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > max)
        {
            max = candidates[i].votes;
            index = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n" , candidates[index].name);

    return;
}
```

i tried to compare max with candidates[i].votes to print the Case : 2

Comment: What do you mean by "2 max values"? Do you mean "2 candidates with max value"? What if more than 2 candidates have the same maximum number of votes? Assuming you want to print all the candidates that have the same maximum number of votes, you need one loop to find the maximum, followed by another loop to print all the candidates that have that maximum number of votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple iterate once over the list of candidates to calculate the maximum number of votes, then iterate a second time to print the names of those that have achieved such numbers.

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int max = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > max)
        {
            max = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(candidates[i].votes==max)
            printf("%s\n" , candidates[i].name);
    }
    return;
}
```